# Replace value with conditions

Tags: r, replace

I'm trying to solve something that it seems to me that is very easy, but I'm a beginner in R and don't know how to.
This is what I would do in Stata:
I create a variable named X1 only with 0's.
then I would do:
replace X1=1 if year==1990 & X2=1

I need to do this in multiple data frames, all of them are the same, but I will have one data frame per year
please help :)

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example using dput()

Comment: Check `ifelse()`

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this answers:

```
> d <- data.frame(x1 = c(0,0,0,0),
+                 year = c(1990, 1991, 1991, 1992),
+                 x2 = c(1,1,2,3))
> d
  x1 year x2
1  0 1990  1
2  0 1991  1
3  0 1991  2
4  0 1992  3
> 
> d[d$year == 1990 & d$x2 == 1, 'x1'] <- 1
> 
> d
  x1 year x2
1  1 1990  1
2  0 1991  1
3  0 1991  2
4  0 1992  3
>
```

You may also try out Duck's suggestion of using ifelse()